# Is there a way I can check if any of the objects in an ArrayList have an object of a specific class?

Tags: java

Assuming I have a class hierarchy where Monkey, Chimp, and Ape classes all inherit from an Animal Class. I now have an ArrayList where some random number of monkeys/chimps/apes are stored inside. Is there a function that can check if any Monkeys exist in that arraylist? Right now I have

```
for (Animal animal1 : Enclosure.HABITABLE_ANIMALS)
     {
       if (animal.getClass().equals(animal1.getClass()))
          {
                    count++;
          }
     }
```

and if the count is greater than 0 it returns true
(in this code you HABITABLE_ANIMALS is the arraylist of animals, and animal is the Monkey)
surely there is a more efficient and better way of doing this

Comment: The most efficient way would be to separately count your classes when adding them to the list.

Comment: That is the correct way to check unless you are tracking them elsewhere. For example, you could create a custom array/collection class that has a flag/bool that is triggered when you add or remove various objects to the collection.

Comment: i know what's inside each, but i have a number of habitats, and each one has its own arraylist of HABITABLE_ANIMALS, (animals who can live in there) so when adding a new animal to a habitat its checking if it can go in there or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to keep counting after you encounter your first Monkey. Also instanceof might be faster than calling Class.equals(), assuming you're OK with subtypes of Monkey to count.

```
boolean hasMonkey(Iterable<? extends Animal> animals){
   for (Animal animal : animals) 
      if (animal instanceof Monkey) 
         return true;
   return false;
}
```

If by efficient your meant 'concise' the streams API has the method anyMatch

animals.stream().anyMatch(i -> i instanceof Monkey);

Answer (score 1):

There is no more efficient way to do this unfortunately, since you'll need to go through the whole `List` anyway (time complexity: `O(n)`)

However, there might be a more expressive way of doing it using `Stream` (but it adds the overhead of creating a `Stream`).

If expressiveness is more important than performance, I'd suggest to go for this solution

```java
Enclosure.HABITABLE_ANIMALS
         .stream()
         .anyMatch(animal.getClass()::isInstance)
```